# Why can't i extend(Inherit) the properties of PrintStream class to a newly derived class

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to override the println(int) by extending the PrintStream class into a newly defined class.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

 class Newer extends PrintStream
{ public void println(int x) {

System.out.println(x);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Newer n=new Newer();

n.println(2);
}

}
```

I have got compilation error saying

```
extendsprintstream.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor PrintStream()
location: class java.io.PrintStream
class Newer extends PrintStream
^
1 error
```

Why am I not able to inherit class PrintStream ?

Comment: Post your code in the question instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: How about posting the _actual_ code you are trying to compile...

Comment: Ok, last bit of advice because I am moving onto other questions - post the _actual real code_ (with proper formatting, not whatever the above is) and the _actual real error_ message. In your question one of these is not correct because your error message does not match your code.We cannot help if you cannot do these simple things before posting your question.

Comment: Did you import PrintStream?

Comment: sorry and thanks for your patience csm_dev . i wanted to check whether we can extend the properties of PrintStream class by inheritance. This is what i was trying by writing basic code . i hope this time i have done proper changes .

Comment: yes i have tried , still compilation error

Comment: yes i have tried , still compilation error

Comment: Then please post the whole class including the import statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Newer` doesn't have a constructor at all, so it gets a default no-args constructor, created by the compiler, that calls `super()`, i.e. the no-args constructor of the base class.
2. The base class is `PrintStream`, and it doesn't have a no-args constructor.

So you get a compilation error. You need to provide a constructor for `Newer()` that calls one of the existing constructors of `PrintStream`, via `super(...)`. For example:

```
public Newer()
{
    super(System.out);
}
```

Then you don't need to override `println()` at all.

Why you're doing this at all is another mystery. You don't need `Newer` at all: you only need `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is no with **extends** but with the fact that you don't use **super** fir your class constructor.
You can't extends another class and overlook this class initialization.

In Java what actually happens when you don't have a constructor-Java compiler makes a default one which call an empty super() call-so it's actually looks like:

```
public Newer{
super();
}
```

And because in your case **PrintStream** doesn't have an empty constructor only the ones you can find in [Oracle help center](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)  you will get compilation error.